# Why is this simple server not accepting connections?

Tags: c++, boost-asio

I just started with boost asio and manipulated a code snippet I found online of a simple server. Here is the code

```
void OnAccept( const boost::system::error_code & ec, boost::shared_ptr< boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket > sock )
{
    if( ec )
    {
        std::cout << "[" << boost::this_thread::get_id()<< "] Error: " << ec << std::endl;  
    }
    else
    {
        std::cout << "[" << boost::this_thread::get_id()<< "] Accepted!" << std::endl;
    }
}

void RunServer()
{
    boost::shared_ptr< boost::asio::io_service > io_service(new boost::asio::io_service);
    boost::shared_ptr< boost::asio::ip::tcp::acceptor > acceptor(new boost::asio::ip::tcp::acceptor( *io_service ));
    boost::shared_ptr< boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket > sock( new boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket( *io_service ) );

    try
    {
        boost::asio::ip::tcp::resolver resolver( *io_service );
        boost::asio::ip::tcp::resolver::query query( "127.0.0.1", boost::lexical_cast< std::string >( 7777 ));
        boost::asio::ip::tcp::endpoint endpoint = *resolver.resolve( query );
        acceptor->open( endpoint.protocol() );
        acceptor->set_option( boost::asio::ip::tcp::acceptor::reuse_address( false ) );
        acceptor->bind( endpoint );
        acceptor->listen( boost::asio::socket_base::max_connections );
        acceptor->async_accept( *sock, boost::bind( OnAccept, _1, sock ) );//Receives only one connection
        std::cout << "Waiting for incoming connections \n";
        while(true)
        {
          Sleep(400);
        }
    }
    catch( std::exception & ex )
    {
        std::cout << "[" << boost::this_thread::get_id()<< "] Exception: " << ex.what() << std::endl;   
    }
}


int main( int argc, char * argv[] )
{
    boost::thread server(RunServer);
    std::cout << "Press any key to stop..\n";
    std::cin.get();
    return 0;
}
```

The code unfortunately is not accepting connections. I tried `telnet localhost 7777` but it does not accept connections any suggestions ?

Comment: Where do you feel the problem may be?  Does it get as far as writing out "Waiting for incoming connections"?

Comment: Yes it does get to that point. But it never accepts a connection. I think its in the RunServer() thread since it ends it also forces its child thread accept connection to end. I therefore added a while loop in it to keep it alive

Comment: as @TAS pointed out i0->service will block until all tasks are done.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are starting an async accept, but you are not allowing the `io_service` to run. You need to either do a synchronous acecpt or call  call `io_service->run()`. The relevant part will become:

```
    std::cout << "Waiting for incoming connections \n";
    io_service->run();
}
```

I suggest that you compare [Daytime.2 - A synchronous TCP daytime server](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/doc/html/boost_asio/tutorial/tutdaytime2.html) and [Daytime.3 - An asynchronous TCP daytime server](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/doc/html/boost_asio/tutorial/tutdaytime3.html)